# Advertisement banner not responsive

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, design

A while ago I opted in to see more ads to test some new feature that was released.

Today thus fired back at me. I was browsing a question in responsive mode in my phone and this obscenity landed on my screen.

A large orange banner much wider then the actual page.

Can we keep this orange within bounds please?

[image]

Also there is this blue gem:

[image]

They both appear to be ads of a similar type directing traffic to SO Jobs.

Comment: [I know of an easy fix for that](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation).

Comment: @Zoe or turn the see reduced ads privilege back on

Comment: @Luuklag - Thanks for notifying us, we're looking into it.

Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Stack, working as a Product Manager in the advertising team.

Comment: @JD-Stack thanks for your response. It appears to be an entire class of ads, as I also uncovered a blue variant, leading to jobs from a different company.

Comment: @Luuklag - I was able to reproduce it. It happens in the specific case whenever you navigate on a mobile device to the desktop site. I'm adding it to our backlog so we can prioritize and fix it.

Comment: See reduced ads in combination with uBlock Origin is what I go with.

Comment: @JD-Stack, yes I mentioned that I use the responsive design (which is the design that will become the standard design in the future in favour of the mobile design) on a mobile device.

Comment: @Luuklag - yeah, you're right. Sorry missed that part of the question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've looked into this and will postpone solving this to when we'll be making the responsive design the standard.